# RowFilter hides reuslts after nothing he can find wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, dataview, rowfilter

I have DataGrid and TextBox for searching

```
 private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
                DataView dvs = (DataView)apps.DataContext;                    
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
                dvs.RowFilter = "Name like '*" + tb.Text + "*'";              
        }
```

It works perfectly when there is matches in dataGrid. For example, I write **wo** - he finds "Microsoft WOrd". Then I can add **n** and there is nothing like this (like **won** ). Okay, I press **Backspace button** and come back to searching **wo** and there is nothing in results... And even when I delete the whole string in textBox I'll never see a string in my datagrid (and in dataview).
I've tried to use *RowStateFilter* but nothing changed.

In the other cases deleting letters works good (when my searching word didn't lead to "nothing found"). if I enter **wor** (he finds Word). If I delete last **r** - it finds everything like %wo%. It works Ok.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using '*' or '%' ?

Comment: in filter? I'm using * *